# How to limit the key of an obejct type to be part of a union in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have a union of server type such as:

```
type Union = 'A' | 'B' | 'C';
```

Then I want to make an obejct type which its key would be part of this Union such as:

```js
// Only use 'A' and 'B' from union
const myObject: { [K in Union]: number } = {
  A: 1,
  B: 2,
} as const;
```

I also want to make the myObject to be const so I could expect these:

```js
console.log(myObject.A); // To be OK
console.log(myObject.C); // To be Error
```

However, when I use `[K in Union]` the compiler would pop an error about:

> Property 'C' is missing in type '{ readonly A: 1; readonly B: 2; }' but required in type '{ A: number; B: number; C: number; }'.(2741)

Can I only pick part of types from the union from the const object?

My purpose is to declare an object which would only have keys from a part of a specified union types.

Comment: Are you just looking for the `satisfies` operator as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NdJynW)? If so I'll write up an answer or find a suitable dupe target; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Never know this `satisfies` keyword but the link looks like what I'm looking for.

Comment: See [the `satisfies` operator documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) and the answers to the linked questions above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
type Union = 'A' | 'B' | 'C';

const myObject = {
  A: 1,
  B: 2,
} as const satisfies { [K in Union]?: number | unknown };
```

I think this should work.